# Fixing locally hosted wordpress site for migration (removing localhost)

Tags: wordpress

A Wordpress novice and have set up my site locally using MAMP. 
Unfortunately all the links to styles and I assume the database etc are by default pathed using 'localhost' so the site works ONLY on my machine. What is the correct way to change this pathing so that wordpress will correctly display the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the database, you can edit the wp-config.php file at the root of your site.

As far as your styles are concerned, you'll have to go through the theme files that you've setup and adjust the relative path to those style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options. Kyle is correct about editing wp-config.php, that will definitely take care of the new DB connection. However, I would advise against a manual adjustment of stylesheets and markup if possible. The easiest way for a novice might be this: export the DB from your local installation using "Settings > Export." Then, in your remote installation, use the WordPress Importer and it should tidy up all the links for you. This has worked for me several times.

You can learn more about other options here: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hosting/how-to-break-a-wordpress-install-and-fix-it-again/

UPDATE: unless of course you've hardcoded "localhost" in your stylesheets and markup. In that case, use one of the solutions in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme uses serialized data, you might have a problem when moving your website by simply doing a find and replace and changing the URL that way. I would recommend following WordPress's guide when you're moving your site.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

It involves using a special script to change the URL of your site.